# Autocomplete Search Box Clickable Links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to JQuery and JS I have been playing around with examples like:

http://www.stepblogging.com/autocomplete-search-using-php-mysqli-ajax-and-jquery/

But i am trying to get the results to also be a link that link off to the location also found in my database which is structured like this currently:

```
 -------------------------
|   Name   |     URL     |
|   name1  |example.com/1|
|   name2  |example.com/2|
```

I can't get to grips with how i can wrap the autocomplete results with a link that will take the user to the URL i want them to go to.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bit more of HTML than a JavaScript question.  To create a link, use the anchor () tag:

`<a href="example.com/1">name1</a>`

`<a href="example.com/2">name2</a>`

So, when you run the JavaScript/jQuery to to get the results to print out in this format and you'll have your link.